# What is the idiomatic way to read urls with a file scheme as filenames for ReadFile?

Tags: go

Is there an idiomatic way to read a file from the system starting from a (file scheme) url and not a path?

I tried this first:

```
fileUrlStr := "file:///path/to/file.json"
jsonBuffer, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(fileUrlStr)
```

This is my current (mostly working version) but I'm concerned there are some gotchas that I'm missing, so I'm hoping there's a more tried and true way to do it:

```
fileUrlStr := "file:///path/to/file.json"
fileUrl, _ := url.Parse(fileUrlStr)
jsonBuffer, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(fileUrl.Path)
```

(Bonus if I can support both `file:///Users/jdoe/temp.json` and `file:///c:/WINDOWS/clock.json` without having to add code-paths accounting for them)

Comment: Personally, I'd use `strings.TrimPrefix(fileUrlStr, "file://")`. I don't think there's any particularly idiomatic way to do it, other than "keep it simple", the general-purpose Go idiom.

Comment: Re. your edit - you can use [`filepath.FromSlash()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#FromSlash) to convert forward slashes to the platform-specific path separator.

Comment: My only concern with that I'll be munging (legal) urls that look like: `file://localhost/path/to/file.json` . (Also, @Adrian, I'm not concerned about the slashes, since all slashes are forward slashes in a url)

Comment: In a URL yes, in a file path, no.

Comment: Basically, the closer I can get to rfc-8089 the better.

Comment: `url` package follows RFC 3986.

Comment: Ok, then what's the golang idiom for converting file scheme uri into system specific paths?

Answer (score 4):

Using `net/url`, the solution that you were using, is the correct one.

It's properly deals with hostnames and paths across platforms and also gives you a chance to check the url scheme is the file scheme.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {

    for _, path := range []string{
        "file:///path/to/file.json",
        "file:///c:/WINDOWS/clock.json",
        "file://localhost/path/to/file.json",
        "file://localhost/c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi",

        // A case that you probably don't need to handle given the rarity,
        // but is a known legacy win32 issue when translating \\remotehost\share\dir\file.txt 
        "file:////remotehost/share/dir/file.txt",

    } {
        u, _ := url.ParseRequestURI(path)
        fmt.Printf("url:%v\nscheme:%v host:%v Path:%v\n\n", u, u.Scheme, u.Host, u.Path)
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is, and this is the point of the question, that the result on Windows gives you "/c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi". Try and pass that filename to ReadFile it won't find the file. You have to strip the leading / off first.